# Is downloading files on Android possible when the app is in background without a charger?

Tags: android, download, background-process

I'm developing an app where I need to download a 200-300 mb file from the web. Today I noticed a strange behaviour.

I always have my phone plugged to the PC with a cable with Android Monitors running in IntelliJ. Everyhing was running nice, files were downloading even when I was clicking the 'home' button in the middle of the process and I always got a notification to the menu that the downloading has finished - and it was really, complately finished.

Today I unplugged my phone from the pc/cable and opened the app. The downloading process starts but when I click 'home' and the app goes to the background, it won't finish, it won't even continue. It freezes the networking thread or something connected with it.

I read some, and I remember that some popular apps like for example 'Hearthstone' game had the same problem. If you go to the menu, downloading stops.

I figured it out that this is caused by the charger. If the phone is charging when the files are being downloaded, everything is ok.

**And my question is.**

```
Is there any Android permission that will allow me to do this?
```

I heard that it can be changed on the device's settings, but this is a bad solution.

```
Is there any possibility to download files in background, without a charger and without user's interaction with the settings?
```

I'll also add that I'm using LibGDX engine but it doesn't matter, I can use all of the Android's features.

Comment: You need to hold a `WakeLock`, and possibly a `WifiLock` (if you are downloading on WiFi and want to try to keep WiFi going until you complete your download).

Comment: It is not the charger. Rather, change the approach to handling this downloading, by using background threads or a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there are two aspects that can limit the network:

- Restrict background data - an option that you can set on each application in Data Usage settings
- Power saving option which automatically makes a limit on the networking and more.

Extra: when device is connected to a charger, power saving is disabled by default - that's why it was working.

Comment: What was your solution in the end?

Comment: Please do not include phrases like "after 4 hours" or "....wait for it.....". This is not a forum where you should excel at entertaining story telling, but rather with concise descriptions of solutions.

Comment: I solved it by displaying a dialog where user can choose if he wants to disable the power saving mode or not.